Solid state relay switch circuit with Omron G3MB-202P
could somebody explain the use of the Zener diode and capacitor in the schematic of a switch utilizing an Omron G3MB-202P?


The Zener is a crude over-voltage protection component for the SSR diode (pins 3, 4).  C1 is just a "smooth operator", there to help smooth transients introduced by S1 & T1.  C1 will also help for supply storage/bypassing from J1 Pin 1 (+5V In), perhaps reducing ripple on the 5V line.  The circuit would likely operate fine without either one (but less-good).  However, the circuit will fail all the time if either one becomes a short.  Don't let either one become a short.  Note that putting >5V on J1, Pin1 could still result in the destruction of this circuit, if you try hard enough.  Good Luck!
